# Speed this up without Rcpp?

Tags: r, xts

I'm looking to speed up the following algorithm.  I give the function an xts time series and then want to perform a principal components analysis for each time point on the previous X points (I'm using 500 at the moment) and then use the results of that PCA (5 principal components in the following code) to compute some value.  Something like this:

```
lookback <- 500
for(i in (lookback+1):nrow(x))
{   
        x.now <- x[(i-lookback):i]        
        x.prcomp <- prcomp(x.now)
        ans[i] <- (some R code on x.prcomp)
}
```

I assume this would require me to replicate the lookback rows as columns so that `x` would be something like `cbind(x,lag(x),lag(x,k=2),lag(x,k=3)...lag(x,k=lookback))`, and then run `prcomp` on each line?  This seems expensive though.  Perhaps some variant of `apply`?  I'm willing to look into Rcpp but wanted to run this by you guys before that.

**Edit:** Wow thanks for all the responses.  Info on my dataset/algorithm:

1. dim(x.xts) currently = 2000x24.  But eventually, if this shows promise, it will have to run fast (I'll give it multiple datasets).
2. func(x.xts) takes ~70 seconds.  That's 2000-500 prcomp calls with 1500 500x24 dataframe creations.

I attempted to use `Rprof` to see what was the most expensive part of the algo but it's my first time using `Rprof` so I need some more experience with this tool to get intelligible results (thanks for the suggestion).

I think I will first attempt to roll this into an _apply type loop, and then look at parallelizing.

Comment: Yep, Xapply (X='s,l,m,t' :-) ) will help.  Just one thought: unless your existing `for` loop takes significant time to complete, don't bother.

Comment: When you profile the code, what takes the most time?  Moving the loop to compiled code won't help much if most of the time is spent in `prcomp`.  Have you tried putting the loop in a function and byte-compiling it?

Comment: Or writing the inner part of the loop as a function `doit(i, x) { ... }` and using `parallel::mclapply((lookback+1):nrow(x), doit, x)` to evaluate in parallel (assuming R-2.14 and non-Windows; if the data is not too big and you're on Windows, then `parallel::parSapply` with some additional code might work).

Comment: If each PCA shares 499 out of 500 of the data points as the next one, is there much of a difference between them?  Can't you just do PCA on every tenth time point?

Comment: How big is your matrix `x`? ...and how long does the whole thing currently take?

Comment: ..and shouldn't it be `x.now <- x[(i-lookback):i, ]` if `x` is a matrix? (note the extra comma to select a subset of rows, not vector elements).

Comment: @Tommy: `x` isn't a matrix, it's an xts object.  `[.xts` returns all columns if `j` is missing.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich - oops. I change my question then: How big is the xts vector `x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my 4 core desktop, if this wouldn't complete in a reasonable time-frame, I would run the chunk using something along the lines of (not tested):

```
library(snowfall)
sfInit(parallel = TRUE, cpus = 4, type = "SOCK")
lookback <- 500
sfExport(list = c("lookback", "x"))
sfLibrary(xts)

output.object <- sfSapply(x = (lookback+1):nrow(x),
    fun = function(i, my.object = x, lb = lookback) {
        x.now <- my.object[(i-lb):i]      
        x.prcomp <- prcomp(x.now)
        ans <- ("some R code on x.prcomp")

        return(ans)
    }, simplify = FALSE) # or maybe it's TRUE? depends on what ans is
```